# Script seems to not to call another script until it runs through several times

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Pretty much what the title says. Console is blocked by the owner of my device. Can't get around it. I'll leave notes in code about the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Penalty Shootout</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="all-docs.css">
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="game" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid   #000000;position:absolute;top:10px;left:10%">
</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("game");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var ballX;
var ballY;
var ballZ;
var ballXVel;
var ballYVel;
var ballZVel;
var mx=0;
var my=0;
var oldx;
var oldy;
var kick = 0;


document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseUpdate, false);


function onMouseUpdate(e) {
  if (!kick){
  kick = !kick
  mx = e.pageX;
  my = e.pageY;
  ballXVel = (mx-250)/20;
  ballYVel = (my-380)/20;
  ballZVel = -2;
  renderWorld();
  ballLoop();

  }
}


function renderWorld(){

ctx.fillStyle = "#3355FF";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,380);
ctx.strokeRect(50,100,400,300);
ctx.fillStyle = "#00DD00";
ctx.fillRect(0,380,500,120);

}


function renderBall(){

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ballX,ballY,ballZ,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke(); 
  ctx.closePath();

}


function reset(){

  ballX=250;
  ballY=380;
  ballZ=40;
  ballXVel=0;
  ballYVel=0;
  ballZVel=0; 

}


function detectKick(){

  oldx=mx;
  oldy=my;

  loopDetectKick();

}
function loopDetectKick(){

  if(oldx==mx&&oldy==my){

    setTimeout(loopDetectKick(),100);

  }else{


    renderWorld();
    setUpPhysics();

  }

}


function setUpPhysics(){

var ballXVel;
var ballYVel;
var ballZVel;

}
```

applyPhysics and ballLoop are whats wrong. I'm trying to make it move slowly, which I though I had achieved with this code, however it seems to run all the code, and update the canvas later.

```
function applyPhysics(){

ballX = ballX + ballXVel;
ballY = ballY + ballYVel;
ballZ = ballZ + ballZVel;
ballXVel = ballXVel * 0.9;
ballYVel = ballYVel * 0.9;
ballZVel = ballZVel * 0.9;
renderWorld();
renderBall();
  if(ballZ>10){
    setTimeout(ballLoop(), 100)
  }else{


  }

}
function ballLoop(){

  applyPhysics();

}

renderWorld();
reset();
renderBall();
detectKick();


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your setTimeouts. They should _not_ be calling the the function ie `setTimeout(loopDetectKick(),100);`; only a reference to the function should be added: `setTimeout(loopDetectKick,100);`.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Problem solved.